# What would you call an application that allows manual data entry via telephone

Tags: telephony, data-entry

My organization is looking to allow data entry into time tracking software using a standard land line. The data entry would be via key press and not via voice recognition.

An example workflow might be

1. Enter ID #
2. Enter Pin
3. Select job #
4. Choose action (let assume we select "clock in")
5. Enter time in as 24 hour HHMM
6. Confirm
7. User ends the call

I am trying to find out what this type of thing is called so I research more into it.

Answer (score 0):

After some research it looks like this is called "Interactive Voice Response".